# Notification Service Extension:sound file path?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, push

I want to change the UNMutableNotificationContent.sound to play dynamic sound for user. I found comment below:

`// The name of a sound file to be played for the notification.

// The sound file must be contained in the app’s bundle or in the Library/Sounds folder of the app's data container.

// If files exist in both locations then the file in ~/Library/Sounds will be preferred.

+ (instancetype)soundNamed:(NSString *)name __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED;`

For example, push playload will bring a number to client, then I do text to speech work using the extension code.
But I have no permission to move the tts audio file to the ~/Library/Sounds directory of the container app.

If there are any suggestion than can help to solve this problem, or any other method to play the dynamic number sound when the container app is inactive.